# What is the function of peekAtFront in OMNET++

Tags: omnet++

I've found the following code in OMNET++.

```
void Mac::sendDataPacket()
{
    nbTxDataPackets++;
    if (currentTxFrame == nullptr)
        popTxQueue();
    auto packet = currentTxFrame->dup();
    const auto& hdr = packet->peekAtFront<MacHeaderBase>();
    lastDataPktDestAddr = hdr->getDestAddr();
    attachSignal(packet, simTime());
    sendDown(packet);
}
```

Can anyone tell me what is the function of below commands?

```
const auto& hdr = packet->peekAtFront<MacHeaderBase>();
lastDataPktDestAddr = hdr->getDestAddr();
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Packet` in INET is a data structure that represents a real packet (e.g. UDP datagram, IP packet, Ethernet Frame, etc.). An instance of `Packet` may contain other structures inside. To get data at the beginning of a `Packet` the function `popAtFront()` may be used. It removes that data from instance of `Packet`. However, sometimes there is a need to check the structure at the beginning of a Packet without removing it. In that situation `peekAtFront()` may be used. So the line:

```
packet->peekAtFront<MacHeaderBase>();
```

returns the first data structure at the beginning of `packet` - without removing it. Then the structure is casted to `MacHeaderBase`.
Summarizing: that line allows checking whether `packet` contains a MAC frame.

Reference: [INET Developer's Guide - Working with Packets](https://inet.omnetpp.org/docs/developers-guide/ch-packets.html).

Comment: Jerzy, in your answer "To get data at the beginning of a Packet the function popAtFront() may be used.", did you mean data part or header part of a packet? I knew, a packet has three part: header, data and trailer. Also, can you explain the function of ```lastDataPktDestAddr = hdr->getDestAddr();```? Thank you

Comment: 1) I mean the **first part** - usually the first part of a packet is the header, 2) `getDestAddr()` returns the destination address from the MAC header.

Comment: Thanks Jerzy. If I want to add an additional bit to the packet header at MAC layer, and want to set/reset the bit before sending to the receiver, how i can do do that?

Comment: Actually, adding an additional bit to the packet header (e.g. `MacHeader`) is not possible. The same as in a real protocol: the header has fixed structure and it cannot be extended because the receiver will not understand it. However, you can create own header with all bits you want.

Comment: Jerzy, can you explain here how to create own header or i need to post new question on it?

Comment: According to SO rules you should ask a new question with [mcve].